# generics are not supported in -source 1.3

Tags: java, gwt, maven

I have a problem while maven packaging. In this code:

```
public class LoginDialog extends Dialog {

    private final TextField<String> customer;
                          ^here
    private final TextField<String> login1;
    private final TextField<String> password1;
    private final MainController controller= new MainController();
    private String customerId;
    private String login;
    private String password;
```

I have an error like:

```
[ERROR] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Compilation failure
...src/main/java/com/messagedna/web/client/widget/LoginDialog.java:[19,27] error: generics are not supported in -source 1.3
```

what may be the reason of this?

Comment: Fun fact: JDK 1.3 turns 13 years old on May 8!

Comment: well,I don't understand why it was jdk 1.3. i didn't even thought that this can be when creating the app using maven

Comment: Maven should default to at least 1.4 or even 1.5 as far as I know. Try this command `mvn --version` what does it give?

Comment: here you are:`Apache Maven 2.2.1 (rdebian-8)
Java version: 1.6.0_27`

Comment: Hmm, that's odd. I suppose someone has configured your pom.xml to point to 1.3 then. I don't see any other explanation why it would compile as such.

Comment: well, you know, I've tryed to create a new project using maven, but always have the same result.

Comment: @Jops: I've had the same behaviour with `Apache Maven 3.0.4` on the default Ubuntu 13.10 version of maven. Very strange…

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Generics were added in java 1.5. Your maven is compiling for java 1.3.

This can be fixed in one of two ways.

Remove generics so that you can compile for < 1.5

Change the maven configuration to compile for a newer version of java. You should be able to edit your compiler plugin in your pom:

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.5</source>
                <target>1.5</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

This tells maven to compile for 1.5

Answer (score 3):

You need to tell the maven compiler plugin that your code is using a recent java version.  For instance, if you are using java 7, to the following:

```
<plugins>
   <plugin>
     <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
     <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
     <configuration>
       <source>1.7</source>
       <target>1.7</target>
     </configuration>
   </plugin>
</plugins>
```

Answer (score 1):

When you compile your code with `-source 1.3`, the compiler does not support assertions, generics, or other language features introduced after JDK 1.3.

Answer (score 1):

Android studio: It fixes by adding these below lines in the file app build.gradle

`compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }`

Note: use the latest java version, here I'm using java 8

Answer (score 0):

You either need to change your settings so that you're source is set to 1.5+ or remove the generics from your code:

```
private final TextField customer;
```

Answer (score 0):

Generics were only introduced as a feature in Java 5, so when compiling using 3, generics will not be permitted. If you want more info about generics, look [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/intro.html). So you need to either compile using 5 or later or stop using generics.

Answer (score 0):

If you are not using maven and facing similar issue in Intellij editor, probably worth to check Project Settings.
Even if you define Proper JDK, change the "Project language level" and can configure 5 onward.