# Maven uses old plugins on stock Ubuntu installation

Tags: java, maven, ubuntu

For some reason my stock Ubuntu 13.10 Maven installation uses old plugins. Most blatantly the compiler plugin is version 2.0.2 which defaults to Java 1.3:

```
$ mvn --show-version compile                                  
Apache Maven 3.0.4
Maven home: /usr/share/maven
Java version: 1.7.0_25, vendor: Oracle Corporation
Java home: /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: UTF-8
OS name: "linux", version: "3.11.0-14-generic", arch: "amd64", family: "unix"
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[...]
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:2.0.2:compile (default-compile) on project simple: Compilation failure
[ERROR] [...]/simple/src/main/java/org/sonatype/mavenbook/App.java:[11,17] error: generics are not supported in -source 1.3
```

Compilation fails because of `ArrayList<Integer> a = new ArrayList<Integer>();` which uses generics. **Now I know I can force maven to use the current compiler plugin** (see [generics are not supported in -source 1.3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15746264/generics-are-not-supported-in-source-1-3)) **but I would rather solve the root cause than to add every plugin I use to my *pom* file.** If there is no other solution I will add plugin specifications to a parent pom, but I would still be interested by which rational maven chooses plugin versions.

**My environment:** I have no settings.xml in my local m2 repository, my (stock Ubuntu) `/etc/maven/m2.conf` looks like this:

```
main is org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli from plexus.core

set maven.home default ${user.home}/m2

[plexus.core]
optionally ${maven.home}/lib/ext/*.jar
load       ${maven.home}/lib/*.jar
```

And my `/etc/maven/settings.xml` is essentially empty except for a few comments and empty xml tags. The projects pom is the default generated by `mvn archetype:generate -DgroupId=org.sonatype.mavenbook -DartifactId=simple -Dpackage=org.sonatype.mavenbook -Dversion=1.0-SNAPSHOT`:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>org.sonatype.mavenbook</groupId>
  <artifactId>simple</artifactId>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>

  <name>simple</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

Any advice?

Comment: Do you have a parent pom defined? Maybe it still specifies the compiler plugin version?

Comment: @NickDK: No, there is none :(

Answer (score 1):

You can (and should) specify the Maven compiler plugin manually in your `pom.xml`

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.7</source>
                <target>1.7</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

I have no idea why Maven 3.0.4 uses such an early Maven compiler plugin version but I don't think it's an Ubuntu specific problem. I don't know a general solution bould it would require local configuration. You want to avoid that because it makes your build platform dependent. The advantage of explicitly specifying this in your pom is that you can just build your project on any other machine without facing the same issue again.

If don't want to do this in every project you can use a parent pom. See [default maven compiler setting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2531650/default-maven-compiler-setting)

Comment: Thanks, but If possible I would like to avoid doing that for every plugin that I use and instead solve the root cause.

Comment: Set up a parent pom.  They're great for all sorts of things.

Comment: Added some information about general solution and parent pom.